# I cannot find out how to do this anywere in my book

Tags: css

How do I create a style rule that sets the font color to white in older browsers, and to white with 50% opacity in newer browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a stacked rule. Put the declaration that is most widely supported first, due to the cascading nature of CSS. Older browsers that cannot interpret `rgba` will ignore the line. Newer browsers that can, on the other hand, will accept both, but since the `rgba` declaration comes last, it will be the one that takes precedence.

```
p {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

ps: Of course `<p>` is just a generic element that I've used. You can use any selector.